# Joint expectations in Python or R

Tags: python, r, probability

$X$ and $Y$ are Bivariate Normally distributed as $N(0,1)$ with a correlation coefficient of $p$.

Is there any way to find the expectation of $f(x)*g(y)$ - Let $f(x)$ this be a function of $x$ which is Integrable as well as Differentiable

$E[f(x)*g(y)]$? Where $g(y) = 1$, if $y>c$. $g(y) = 0$, otherwise

Is there any way to do this in Python? Or in some other Language like R?

I am aware of the `multivariate_normal()` function under `scipy.stats`.

```
import scipy.stats as st

a = st.multivariate_normal()
```

Is there any way we can use this combined with some other method?

It will be great if someone can help me with an analytical solution also. For example we can take $$ f(x) = exp(x)$$

Comment: Do you want a closed form analytical solution (using laws of probability and calculus) or are you looking for a way to estimate the expectation using R or Python?

Comment: If you are looking only for a numerical solution, then the easiest one is to conduct a Monte Carlo simulation...

Comment: Hi. I am more interested in finding the expectation in Python or R. I am not sure if a closed form will be possible or not. If you can help me with the Python or R code it will be great

Comment: On the other hand if you can help me with an analytical solution that will be great too. We can consider $$f(x) = exp(x)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rather easily approximate the expected value of $f(X)g(Y)$ using simulation. For instance, here is the R code to simulate the expected value of $X^2e^Y$ with $\rho = 0.2$ using 1 million samples:

```
# Parameters for calculation
f <- function(x) x^2
g <- function(y) exp(y)
rho <- 0.2

# Approximate expectation
library(mvtnorm)
set.seed(144)
simulated <- rmvnorm(1e6, c(0, 0), rbind(c(1, rho), c(rho, 1)))
mean(f(simulated[,1]) * g(simulated[,2]))
# [1] 1.713411
```

Similar code can approximate the expectation in python:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(144)
simulated = np.random.multivariate_normal([0, 0], [[1, 0.2], [0.2, 1]], 1000000)
print(np.average(simulated[:,0] ** 2 * np.exp(simulated[:,1])))
# 1.70735583203
```

Analytically, the expectation is given by the following expression, based on the [bivariate normal pdf](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BivariateNormalDistribution.html):

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)g(y)\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\exp\bigg[-\frac{x^2-2\rho xy + y^2}{2(1-\rho^2)}\bigg] dxdy
$$

Whether this has an analytical solution depends on the functions $f$ and $g$.